# nginx error! The page you are looking for is not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, puma

I am building a test app using AWS EC2 with Nginx and Puma following this tutorial

```
https://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/
```

I am also able to deploy the app successfully with `Capistrano`.
The app also works in development.
I am using Rails 5 and Ruby 2.3.1 in development and production.

At this moment I have two pages working in development but not working in production.

In production when using this URL

```
http://ec2-54-226-156-103.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
```

I am getting

```
This is the default index.html page that is distributed with nginx on the Amazon Linux AMI. It is located in /usr/share/nginx/html.
```

instead of my home page.

And when I am using this URL

```
http://ec2-54-226-156-103.compute-1.amazonaws.com/contacts
```

I am getting

```
nginx error!
The page you are looking for is not found.
Something has triggered missing webpage on your website. This is the default 404 error page for nginx that is distributed with the Amazon Linux AMI. It is located at /usr/share/nginx/html/404.html
You should customize this error page for your own site or edit the error_page directive in the nginx configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.
```

Don't k know how to fix this.

Here are my config files for Nginx.

```
cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
        #
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl;
#        server_name  localhost;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        # It is *strongly* recommended to generate unique DH parameters
#        # Generate them with: openssl dhparam -out /etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem 2048
#        #ssl_dhparam "/etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:SEED:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!RSAPSK:!aDH:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!SRP;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

and

```
cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

upstream app {
  # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
  server unix:/home/deploy/contactbook/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  root /home/deploy/contactbook/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }

  location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Don't know how to fix these Nginx settings in order to have the app working properly and Nginx serving pages from the app?

If this may be of any help, here is the puma config file from the folder /home/deploy/contactbook/shared

```
cat puma.rb

#!/usr/bin/env puma

directory '/home/deploy/contactbook/current'
rackup "/home/deploy/contactbook/current/config.ru"
environment 'production'

pidfile "/home/deploy/contactbook/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "/home/deploy/contactbook/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state"
stdout_redirect '/home/deploy/contactbook/shared/log/puma_error.log', '/home/deploy/contactbook/shared/log/puma_access.log', true

threads 0,8

bind 'unix:///home/deploy/contactbook/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock'

workers 0

prune_bundler

on_restart do
  puts 'Refreshing Gemfile'
  ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = "/home/deploy/contactbook/current/Gemfile"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `server_name localhost;` in sites-available/default.

I means nginx will only use that server block for requests where the Host header matches "localhost".
For testing, you can set it to `server_name _;` which is the catch-all.

Eventually, you will want to set it to your sites name, like `server_name ec2-54-226-156-103.compute-1.amazonaws.com`, but that can wait until you have a domain name.

Comment: Changed the server name to server_name _; and got the same errors.

Comment: Changed the server_name to server_name ec2-54-226-156-103.compute-1.amazonaws.com and also got the same errors.

Comment: I am very new to Nginx, but my intuition is telling me that the file "/etc/nginx/sites-available/default" is not fetched and and is not used. Actually the folder "sites-available" and the file "default" were created by me since the Nginx installer did not created them.

Comment: The file needs to appear in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` to be used. Typically, this is done by creating the file in `sites-available` (as you have done), and then symlinking it to `sites-enabled`. Restart nginx after that.

Comment: I have no clue how to create such a symlink.

Comment: I don't have a folder sites-enabled. $ cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
-bash: cd: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled: No such file or directory

Comment: Try: `mkdir /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, `chmod 755 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, `ln -s /etc/nginx/site-available/default /etc/nginx/site-available`

Comment: Executed: sudo mkdir /etc/nginx/sites-enabled, sudo chmod 755 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled, sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/site-available/default .

Comment: Result for ls -l is lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Sep 23 09:54 default -> /etc/nginx/site-available/default

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo - it's `sites-available`, not `site-available`

Comment: ln -s /etc/nginx/site-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/etc/nginx/sites-available/default’: File exists

Answer (score 0):

Something has triggered missing webpage on your website. This is the default 404 error page for nginx that is distributed with Red Hat Enterprise Linux. It is located /usr/share/nginx/html/404.html

You should customize this error page for your own site or edit the error_page directive in the nginx configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.

For information on Red Hat Enterprise Linux, please visit the Red Hat, Inc. website. The documentation for Red Hat Enterprise Linux is available on the Red Hat, Inc. website.